# How do I prevent cassandra get command displaying values in hex

Tags: get, cassandra, hex

I'm just beginning with Cassandra and I have the peculiar problem that whenever I retrieve a value is returns in hex (please see below).  I've googled for this without success.  I'd appreciate any help that may be forthcoming.  Thanks!

```
[default@MyKeyspace] set User['hirsch']['email'] = 'swhirsch@nyc.rr.com'; 
Value inserted.
[default@MyKeyspace] get User['hirsch']['email'];                        
=> (column=656d61696c, value=7377686972736368406e79632e72722e636f6d, timestamp=1292294713343000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell cassandra what kind of data are in your column values:

update column family User with column_metadata=[{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}];

Comment: excellent!  Thanks alot!  Don't know why I couldn't find that in the cassandra documentation!